# How to display a dialog in BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry-jde

How do I display a dialog to the user asking him if he wants to continue, with a choice of yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the `Dialog`s [provided by BB](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html) like `Dialog.ask(someNumber,"Your message");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog d = new Dialog("Do you want to continue?", new String[]{"Yes","No"},  new int[]{Dialog.OK,Dialog.CANCEL}, Dialog.OK, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.QUESTION)){
                    public void setChangeListener(FieldChangeListener listener) {
                        if(d.getSelectedValue() == Dialog.OK){
                             //true part                                
                        }
                        else{
                             //false part
                        }
                    };
                };
d.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here late but maybe helpful to someone in future:

```
int ans =  Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Do you want to continue?", Dialog.YES);

    if (ans == Dialog.YES) 
        // Continue
    else
        // Do not Continue
```

The third parameter states the default selected option which is set to the `Yes` option.

Here's an article on how to work with different [types of Blackberry dialogs](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/01/bb-java-dialog.html).

Answer (score -3):

use JOptionPane :

```
int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to continue ?");
if (int == 0){
   // code for continue
}
else {

}
```